# formvalidation v1.3.0 not working with requirejs

Tags: requirejs, formvalidation-plugin, formvalidation.io

I have the following code that is currently WORKING code

Form:

```
<form id="demoForm" method="POST">
    // bootstrap form...
</form>
```

on page Script:

```
<script src="~/scripts/Framework/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/Framework/bootstrap-4/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.35.3/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/Plugins/formvalidation-1.3.0/js/FormValidation.full.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/script/Plugins/formvalidation-1.3.0/js/plugins/Bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="~/script/Plugins/formvalidation-1.3.0/js/plugins/J.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
$('#demoFrom').formValidation({
plugins: {
declarative: new FormValidation.plugins.Declarative({ html5Input: true }),
trigger: new FormValidation.plugins.Trigger(),
bootstrap: new FormValidation.plugins.Bootstrap(),
submitButton: new FormValidation.plugins.SubmitButton(),
icon: new FormValidation.plugins.Icon({
    valid: 'fa fa-check',
    invalid: 'fa fa-times',
    validating: 'fa fa-refresh'
})
}
});
});
</script>
```

But when I try with requirejs its not. The NOT WORKING code below:

```
<script src="~/scripts/Framework/require.js" data-main="~/scripts/app.js">
```

App.js:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '/Scripts/',
    paths: {
        jquery: 'Framework/jquery-3.3.1.min',
        bootstrap:'Framework/bootstrap-4/js/bootstrap.bundle.min',
        es6Shim: 'Framework/es6-shim.min',
        fvMain: 'Plugins/formvalidation-1.3.0/js/FormValidation.full.min',
        fvBootstrap: 'Plugins/formvalidation-1.3.0/js/plugins/Bootstrap.min',
        fvJQuery: 'Plugins/formvalidation-1.3.0/js/plugins/J.min'
    },
    shim: {
        jquery: {
            exports: '$'
        },
        bootstrap: {
            deps:['jquery']
        },
        fvBootstrap: {
            deps: ['es6Shim', 'fvMain','fvJQuery']
        }
    }
});

require(['jquery', 'bootstrap'],
    function ($) {
//... some other tasks
require[('fvBootstrap'), function(){
$('#demoFrom').formValidation({
plugins: {
declarative: new FormValidation.plugins.Declarative({ html5Input: true }),
trigger: new FormValidation.plugins.Trigger(),
bootstrap: new FormValidation.plugins.Bootstrap(),
submitButton: new FormValidation.plugins.SubmitButton(),
icon: new FormValidation.plugins.Icon({
    valid: 'fa fa-check',
    invalid: 'fa fa-times',
    validating: 'fa fa-refresh'
})
}
});
});

});
```

in the requirejs code I am getting the error "FormValidation is not defined"

I have tried to contact the developer with this issue without any luck. Can anyone help me on this, please?

Answer (score 0):

Check your imports again, i guess you are including this library but actually you don't have it in your directory.
check this import

```
<script src="~/scripts/Plugins/formvalidation-1.3.0/js/FormValidation.full.min.js"></script>
```